# Как сделать рендер только видимого объекта в том виде в котором вижу его на сцене (без затемнения)?

Tags: blender

При попытке выполнить рендер в блендере рендерятся все объекты которые видны на сцене.
Плюс всё затемняется.
А как получить простое png изображение того что сейчас отображает камера, то есть только видимые объекты и в том видео в котором их видно в режиме редактирования?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View -> Viewport Render Image.

На рендере объекты отключаются фотоаппаратом в аутлайнере